# Timeout doesn't always trigger with JQuery deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, deferred, event-loop

I have this example which I need to work with JQuery deferred and need to wait for an API call to get some data but in case the API response will take too long, I am setting up a timeout and resolve(undefined).

Things are working fine in this code except that in 1 percent of sessions I am seeing the API call had taken longer than "timeout" but the timeout didn't trigger and didn't resolve(undefined) and waited for the API response time. This 1 percent is happening across different browsers.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks for your help in advance

Here is the code:

```
public static setup(setupUrl: string, configOptions: IDefaultConfigOptions, timeout: number): JQueryPromise<string> {
            const setupPromise = $.Deferred<string>();
            this.startDefaultSetup(setupInUrl, configOptions, timeout, setupPromise);
            return setupPromise;
        }

private static startDefaultSetup(setupUrl: string, configOptions: IDefaultConfigOptions, timeout: number, setupPromise: JQueryDeferred<string>): void {
    let setupPromiseResolved = false;

    // Set timeout for setup
    let setupTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!setupPromiseResolved) {
            setupPromiseResolved = true;
            setupTimeout = undefined;
            setupPromise.resolve(undefined);
        }
    }, timeout);

    // this function calls api and has this defaultSetupResult callback
    getAccount(configOptions, defaultSetupResult => {
        if (!setupPromiseResolved) {
            setupPromiseResolved = true;
            if (setupTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(setupTimeout);
                setupTimeout = null;
            }
            this.handleSetupResult(defaultSetupResult, setupUrl, setupPromise);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a solution for a simmilar problem. I ve read about promises. Basically function will wait for result and process to next one. This code snippet below will give you a basic indication what I mean:

```
<script>
    $( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "p" ).append( "Started..." );

      $( "div" ).each(function( i ) {
        $( this ).fadeIn().fadeOut( 1000 * ( i + 1 ) );
      });

      $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
        $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
      });
    });
</script>
```

For future references use link below or google. Good luck

[JQuery promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)